# 8 - Is It Possible To Create Routes Through The Admin

Tags: routes

**Question:** Is there a way for users to create routes in the admin?

**Issue:** I have a bunch of nodes and tax terms that are being used in Views but no where else. They shouldn't be accessible to the public either. Changing their path to /admin didn't give me the result I wanted, where in D7, that would automatically set them to the admin theme and I could set the permissions that way. I haven't found a decent entity module to create them like I want either.

**Solution:** Created a module that used a wildcard route. Then create a service that uses RouteSubscriberBase and alterRoutes to block any access to it without X permission.

I think there is some potential for others to use this but cannot find a way to set the routes to be blocked through the admin.  x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out the [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module.

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should
>   happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its
>   own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel.
>   Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own
>   page, through node/xxx.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. Wish I had asked before going through the trouble of making my own module.